# I have an openweathermap API issue with iOS app

Tags: ios, browser, openweathermap

I am using openweathermap API in my iOS app.

Below is my URL which I am calling to get weather info.

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=21.282778&lon=-157.829444&APPID=MYAPPID&lang=en-US

When I open this URL in a browser I get a proper response.

But when I call the web service from my iOS app, I do not get a response.

I get the following error:

```json
{
    cod = 401;
    message = "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info.";
}
```

I had created an API key from this URL:
[Create API key on Open Wheather](http://home.openweathermap.org/)

Comment: Like this http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98&lang=en-US

Comment: MYAPPID is just temperory for here. I am putting actual value.

Comment: check my url in above comment i just replaced a valid appid from openweathermap site

Comment: I also tried same thing from URL provided by you. But it has same result. In browser it shows result But showing same error in iOS App.

Comment: post your code how you sending request on server.

Comment: It is already showing error code. So i don't think there is any issue regarding sending request on server.

Comment: error code shows you are setting in a wrong way that server is unable to get. below is a working code place it in ViewDidLoad method and check response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a&lang=en-US"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                            completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        NSError* errorObj;
        NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                              JSONObjectWithData:data
                              options:kNilOptions
                              error:&errorObj];

        NSLog(@" response is %@",json);

    }];

    [task resume];
```

You app id should be valid. I have hardcoded the url for demonstration.

Comment: Thanks. Actually issue with my request. I was sending "q=London,uk&appid=44db6a862fba0b067b1930da0d769e98&lang=en-US" indo as parameters. After sending full url in request i was able to get data.

Comment: @Maria - Can you send me the full request, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @nOObiOS post a separate question and your current code.